# How to customize Tiny MCE jquery version?

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I want to implement and customize Tiny MCE jquery version. Don't know how to :(

Comment: What are you looking to do? We can't help if we don't know how you want to customize.

Comment: Here's how to customise it to appear invisible: remove the `$(element).tinymce(...)` code. There's infinite number of things you might want, are we supposed to guess? :)

Comment: Do you want to customize tinymce or jquery? - obviously a pkugin seems to be a good choice depending on what you want (this wont work if you need to twek the tinymce core functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a plugin, if that's what you want to do, for Tiny MCE is no different for the jQuery version than the standard version.

Here's an excellent tutorial which explains how to try it: http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Create_plugin/3.x

Were my karma a bit higher I'd link you a second one to boot.